# How to filter salesforce case object using SQOP API based on parameters like ""Parent Case Product Description"

Tags: java, salesforce

I am trying to get list of cases opened and assigned to engineering team and specific to few products.

I am using SOAP API and trying to first filter the cases based on criteria s like "Parent Case Product Description=some product", Type=Engineering Escalation etc. and then retrieving owner name, account name, Case Product Version etc.
"Parent Case Product Description" and Type are additional fields based on which we can filter the cases from Salesforce GUI.

However I am not able to filter the cases based on above mentioned fields as these are not fields of case object.
I checked this here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_case.htm

I can access the field(which are not part of case object), e.g. account name field is not there in case object but I could retrieve it using "case.Account.name" in SOQL query.
But my problem is, I could not find way to access parameters like "Parent Case Product Description=some product" and Type=Engineering Escalation.

I would like to achieve something like below,
SELECT ... FROM case where "Parent Case Product Description" LIKE "some product name" AND Type = 'Engineering Escalation';

Please provide me some pointers on how to access parameters mentioned in where clause.

Note: Please note that the "Type" I mentioned in above example is different from "case object field" - type.

Following is the part of code I am trying.

```
Private void querySample() {
  String soqlQuery = "SELECT Case.ParentId, AccountId, CaseNumber, Subject, OwnerId, Case.Account.name FROM Case'";
  try {
     QueryResult qr = connection.query(soqlQuery);
     boolean done = false;

     if (qr.getSize() > 0) {
        System.out.println("\nLogged-in user can see "
              + qr.getRecords().length + " records.");

        while (!done) {
           System.out.println("");
           SObject[] records = qr.getRecords();
           for (int i = 0; i < records.length; ++i) {
              Case con = (Case) records[i];
              String CNumber = con.getCaseNumber();
              String Csubject = con.getSubject();
              String CownerId = con.getOwnerId();
              com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.Account CaseAccount = con.getAccount();
              String name = CaseAccount.getName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Product Description" is a custom field on Case and it is not a long test area (which are [not allowed in WHERE clauses](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm)), the SOQL query would look something this this:

```
SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Parent.Product_Description__c LIKE '%something%' AND Type__c = 'Engineering Escalation'
```

One thing I noticed in your query is that for parent relationships, you were prefixing `Case` (e.g. `Case.ParentId`) which is not really needed (i.e. just `ParentId` will do). This doesn't really matter, but just calling it out because it be what was leading to some confusion about traversing relationships.

Also, for the task at hand here, it might be solved better with a [SOSL search](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm), rather than a [SOQL query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm). SOSL will allow you to find text in a long text area and can search across the whole object, which might work better and should be faster because the data is indexed. It might find a little too much, but it does allow you to filter records down and you do further filtering with SOQL or in your Java code.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for reply.
I tried query you mentioned however it gives below error.
Any guess why its complaining?
   

[MalformedQueryFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='MALFORMED_QUERY'
 exceptionMessage='
 case.product2.name FROM Case Parent.Product_Description__c LIKE
                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:109
Invalid alias Parent.Product_Description__c'
]
 row='1'
 column='109'
]
]

Comment: You are missing the `WHERE` keyword in your WHERE clause. That is, it should be `...FROM Case WHERE Parent.Product_Description__c...`

Comment: Query:
`SELECT Case.ParentId, CaseNumber, Subject FROM Case WHERE Parent.Product_Description__c LIKE '%Control C%'"

Output:

[InvalidFieldFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_FIELD'
 exceptionMessage='
case.Account.name FROM Case WHERE Parent.Product_Description__c LIKE
                                  ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:95
No such column 'Product_Description__c' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.'
]`

Comment: Ryan it would be great help if you could give me pointers. I am new with Salesforce API.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I was able to resolve the issue. First I determined case table fields using describeSObjectsSample code given in SOAP API documentation. Then provided exact custom parameters as filter. Query was something like this `SELECT CaseNumber, Subject FROM Case where Type__c ='Engineering Escalation' AND Parent_Case_Product_Description__c LIKE '%product name%'`

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that "Parent Case Product Description" was just a simple custom field on your Case object. I was thinking you wanted to traverse the `Parent` relationship and access a field there. You might actually want to change your data model so that you can do that, but that's another story. Either way, so that you don't have to do sobjectDescribes in Java just to write your query, you might want to try using [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com), which will describe your objects and help you write and execute simple queries.